# Where to mount efi partition?

Tags: bootloader, partitioning, uefi

I have an existing efi partition used for a windows installation.
I want to install grub to it, for dual boot.

The tutorials say to mount this efi-partition (in my case /dev/sdb1) to /mnt/boot.
Now my question is, to which /mnt/boot should i mount?

I am in a shell from a linux on a usb-stick.
Should i make a directory /mnt/boot inside the persistant linux installation that i want to boot. I can just do that by mounting it first.
Or should i make a volatile directory /mnt/boot from the shell of the usb-stick and mount the bootpartition there?

I hope i described my question in an understandable way.
Another way to describe it:

Should i create /boot/efi inside the root_partition containing the linux i want to boot, using the following commands?

```
root@archiso ~ # mkdir my_mountpoint
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/<root_partition> my_mountpoint
root@archiso ~ # mkdir my_mountpoint/boot/efi
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/sdb1 my_mountpoint/boot/efi
```

Or should i create /boot/efi directly in the volatile filesystem, using the following commands?

```
root@archiso ~ # mkdir /mnt/boot
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you read the full instruction set before starting actually doing what is described.
This should answer your question.

Now; in most cases, nowadays - mounting something under /mnt/ is a temporary thing, something you do to set up, install, change things.
While having it that way you arrange, prepare to have the permanent setup.